# Select linked with duplicate vertices

Tags: selection-tools

I have a model in which sharp edges are achieved with duplicate vertices. I would like to be able to select linked vertices, in such a way that duplicate vertices are considered 'linked'. Is there any way to do that?

(I can of course remove duplicate vertices first, but then these edges become smooth, which is not what I want).

Comment: Have you considered using [edge split modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html)

Comment: The problem is that the model I need to work with already has these duplicate vertices. But if there is an automatic way to remove duplicate vertices and make the merged edges split at the same time, so as to keep the edges sharp, then that would work. Is there?

Comment: Automatic tool is Edge Split modifier or AutoSmooth option in Object data tab. It implies rebuilding sharp edges using either of these. There isn't default way to select linked geometry by selecting only one mesh element from only one mesh; to select linked you will have to select at least a vertex from each mesh

Answer (score 0):

Place your Cursor on the Linked vertex in the Edit Mode and Press L on your keyboard, it should select the linked vertex

Comment: No, it doesn't with duplicate vertices, because those duplicate vertices are not linked to the original selected one.

Comment: Geometry overlapping another geometry isn't considered linked even if it is placed in the same spot so this will not allow to select e.g. all faces of a cube which has its vertices split at edges